# Apps Script: How to create 'mailApp' ui alert message if no recipient email address keyed into html form input for recipient email onClick?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to build in a feature that produces an alert message for a user if said user clicks the 'Send Email' button in my HTML Service form to execute my server-side mailapp 'sendmail' function without having first keyed in a target recipient email address into the html ui.  Currently, i just have one message coded to pop up (function () 'eMailSent') for both successful and unsuccessful attempts.

```
<input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" 
  size="60" /><br>
<input type="button" value="send Email" class="button button2" 
  onClick="checkEmail()" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="button button2" 
  onClick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form>
  <script>
   function checkEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementByID("emailInput").value;
    if(email.indexOf("@")!=-1){
    console.log("google Script was run")
    }
    else{alert("Please enter a valid email")
    }}
  </script>
```

Comment: Syntax error: "getElementById()" not "ID"

Comment: Also please look at this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to help you troubleshoot errors in websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `checkEmail()` function to make sure a valid email was entered, then run your google.script functions. Below is an example of how you can achieve that in javascript.

```js
function checkEmail(){
var email = document.getElementById("email").value
if(email.indexOf("@")!= -1){
//google.script.run.send(this.parentNode);
//google.script.run.emailSent(this.parentNode)
console.log("Goolge SCript was Run")
}
else{
console.log("Invalid Email ID")
alert("Please enter a valid email")
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id ="email">
<input type="button" value="send Email" class="button button2" onClick="checkEmail()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it, Jack.  For some reason, nothing happens upon click when I've got an invalid email keyed in.  Wondering if there might be an error that we're not seeing.  Thank you very much, for your help.

Comment: Does nothing happen in your code or in the snippet above?

Comment: Jack,  Sorry for not iterating that!  The output is nothing in my code.        <script>
       function checkEmail(){
  var email = document.getElementByID("emailInput").value;
  if(email.indexOf("@")!=-1){
  console.log("google Script was run")
  }
  else{
  alert("Please enter a valid email")
  }}
  </script>

Comment: What error do you get on the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) when you click the button. Also, please edit your question with the last code, so it is much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Jack, I've edited my original script post above to now include the updated code I am attempting to execute.  Sorry for being somewhat confusing.  I am not currently getting either error message because I am trying out the error message with the above iteration of code for an invalid entry in the email input.

Comment: Jack, everything triggering nicely, with the exception of the email send function upon click.  Can you take a look?

Comment: Worked through it.  Rearranged some things, and now works beautifully.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Jack!